# Unable to apt update while sever is available

Tags: debian, apt

I just installed debian 11 so want to update it.
I do `sudo apt update` but get few strings like

```
Err:1 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye InRelease
```

I have tried to replace deb.debian.org with the nearest mirror but it didn't help.

here is my source.list:

```
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye main contrib non-free
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye main contrib non-free

deb http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye/updates main contrib non-free
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye/updates main contrib non-free

deb http://security.debian.org/debian-security bullseye-updates main contrib non-free
deb-src http://security.debian.org/debian-security bullseye-updates main contrib non-free
```

**I have checked, all addresses from source.list are available via ping**

If you have seen this issue before on stackoverflow, that's because they down voted question and said me to post such questions here.

Comment: Usually the line `Err:1 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye InRelease` is followed by one or more lines denoting the actual error condition. Please post that complete error. - Note that *"available via ping"*  means that there is some basic network connectivity but that is not a conclusive result that your system can actually connect via http to a Debian mirror... - better than ServerFault might even be  http://unix.stackexchange.com
 the Q&A for users of Linux, FreeBSD and other Un*x-like operating systems

Comment: Sorry but i cant show it cause of privacy policy. i also tried to install ubuntu 20.04 on this machine instead of debian but apt still doesn't work